# El nombre de la variable '@' ya se ha declarado

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un módulo para un programa que ya existe en el cual un usuario debe iniciar sesión seleccionando la base de datos a la cual se quiere conectar.

Seguido del inicio de sesión pasa al `form` que estoy mostrando aca abajo, donde importa un documento excel y lo muestra en un `DatagridView`.

Hasta ahí funciona correctamente pero ahora necesito hacer una consulta a la base de datos con la información que había en ese documento excel, quiero consultar con una columna entera del `DatagridView` pero al hacerlo dice que la variable ya esta declarada, sugerencias?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Class1 objeto = new Class1();


    public Form1()
    {
        //Insertar.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static class compartirVariable
    {
        public static String variable;
    }

    private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Insertar.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    private void Btncerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //volver al inicio de sesion
        Dispose();
        login AbrirVentana = new login();
        this.Hide();
        AbrirVentana.Show();
    }



    private void btncargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string hoja = "libro1";    //constante de el numero de la hoja
        string direccion = "1";        //variable receptora de la direccion del documento
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                direccion = openfile1.FileName;
            }
            {
                string pathconn = "Provider = Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=" + direccion + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR= yes;\";"; //conexion concatenando la variable con la direccion del archivo excel
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathconn);
                OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + hoja + "$]", conn); //consulta concatenando la constante con el nombre de la hoja
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                Insertar.DataSource = dt;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception Error){
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + Error.Message);
        }

    }


    private void btnlimpiar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 172.29.110.115; Initial Catalog =" + compartirVariable.variable + "; User ID = sa ; Password = complementos");

        SqlCommand autocomplementar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM y_personal_contratos where contrato = @Contrato", conexion);

        conexion.Open();

        try
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Insertar.Rows)
            {

                //autocomplementar.Parameters.Clear;
                autocomplementar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrato", row.Cells["Contrato"].Value);
                autocomplementar.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception Error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + Error.Message);
        }

        dgvprueba.DataSource = autocomplementar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Claro. Estás añadiendo el  mismo parámetro a la consulta una vez por cada fila. Que es lo que quieres hacer, filtrar por varios contratos?

Answer (score 4):

Mi respuesta original es completamente errónea. No es posible añadir en un sólo parámetro un array de valores para usar con la cláusula `IN` de sql.

La solución es añadir un `SqlParameter` por cada valor que vamos a meter en la query. Podemos usar un método que genere estos parámetros automáticamente por nosotros, y modifique la query para que encaje. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
public static void AddParametersWithValues<T>(SqlCommand cmd,  string parameterName, params T[] values)
{
    var parameterNames = new List<string>();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
    {
        var paramName = @"@param" + i;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, values.ElementAt(i));
        parameterNames.Add(paramName);
    }

    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Replace(parameterName, string.Join(",", parameterNames));
}
```

Una vez que tenemos este método, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SqlCommand autocomplementar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM y_personal_contratos where contrato in (@Contrato)", conexion);

string[] contratos= new string[Insertar.Rows.Count];
for (int i=0;i<Insertar.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    contratos[i]=Insertar.Rows[i].Cells["Contrato"].Value.ToString();
}

AddParametersWithValues<string>(autocomplementar, "@Contrato", contratos);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(autocomplementar);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dgvprueba.DataSource = dt;
```

---

<strike>Si lo que quieres hacer es filtrar por varios contratos, la query sql que estás usando no es correcta. Deberías usar [`IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):</strike>

```
SqlCommand autocomplementar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM y_personal_contratos where contrato in @Contrato", conexion);
```

Y luego debes ir concatenando los contratos en una variable `string` antes de añadir el `sqlparameter`. Algo asi:

```
string condicion="(";
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Insertar.Rows)
{
    condicion+=row.Cells["Contrato"].Value +",";
}
condicion=condicion.Remove(condicion.Length - 1) + ")";
autocomplementar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrato", condicion);
autocomplementar.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

El código puede mejorarse bastante, pero creo que ya te da una pista de como debes hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección pero ahora me sale el siguiente error: `Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@Contrato'.`

Comment: @deiner mi respuesta original era completamente errónea. La he editado para añadir una que si debería funcionar. Pruébala y me comentas, porque lo he hecho de cabeza y es posible que tenga algun error.

Comment: hola, con esos cambios tengo error en la linea de `string[] contratos = new string[Insertar.Rows.Count()];`  en Count, dice **DatagridviewrowCollection no contiene una definicion para "count" ni un metodo de extension accesible "count" que acepte un primer argumento de tipo DatagridviewrowCollection**

Comment: y en `contratos[i] = Insertar.Rows[i].Cells["Contrato"].Value;` no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'object' en 'string'. Ya existe una conversión explicita

Comment: @deiner he actualizado el codigo. Prueba y me comentas

Comment: Hola, ahora no da error, pero puse el codigo dentro de un try y suelta el siguiente mensaje, **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instanca de un objeto**